# PHP mysqli prepared statement block does not execute at all

Tags: php, mysqli

I am working on a web installation script for codeigniter application. It is ajax driven all in one file. So far, it imports the database successfully, writes database configuration to config/database.php and updates config/config.php as well.

However, after the database is imported, I have to add a single admin user and the block that does this never executes for some reason. There is no error and I have removed it out of try catch block to see if anything comes up. Can anyone see what I am not seeing it here please?

The page is pretty long so I will just paste the functions that I think matter:

```
try {
    $db = @new mysqli($host, $user, $dbpwd, $dbname);
    if ($db->connect_errno > 0) {
        $errmsg = 'Unable to connect to database.';
    } else {//connected
        if (import($db)) {
            //installed successfully. Create user now
            //the user is not created and no error is generated at all.
            $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tblusers  (adminfullname,adminemail,adminpwd,confirmed,admintype) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
            $newpass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $adminName = 'Admin';
            $confirm = 1;
            $admintype = 1;
            $statement->bind_param('sssii', $adminName, $email, $newpass, $confirm, $admintype);
            $statement->execute();
            $errmsg = true; //no error
        }
    }
    $db->close();
    echo $errmsg; //back to the calling ajax
}
```

The import function is copied from SO and works straight forward:

```
function import($db) {
    $query = file_get_contents('db.sql');
    try {
        if (@$db->multi_query($query)) {
            do {
                /* store first result set */
                if ($result = @$db->store_result()) {
                    while ($row = @$result->fetch_row()) {
                    }
                    @$result->free();
                }
                /* print divider */
            } while (@$db->next_result());
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }

    //end function
}
```

Comment: you should remove your `@` so your script prints the errors you are receiving. using `@` to suppress your errors is a very bad practice.

Comment: @cmorrissey you are right but without @ it gives technical staff that I didn't want. But i omitted @ from the prepared statements I am having problems with. Does it make sense? The import function works like a charm with or without @ and it can't be the source of the problem, I think since all the tables are imported perfectly.

Comment: The try/catch won't do anything here  - in PHP most errors are not exceptions. When developing and testing code, at the top of your script enable error display. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and remove `@` as suggested  - then post the relevant error messages. If the `else` block is never entered, you should check the output from `echo $db->connect_error` rather than just `connect_errno`.

Comment: It brought one single error: there is no next_result() (defined in import function) but still the tables are imported successfully. I am going to rewrite things without ajax and see if it makes difference and post back.